# JAX-WS handle client disconnect on server

Tags: timeout, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 that supports JEE 6. We have a JAX-WS web service and a client. The client has timeouts set so that is disconnect after 30 seconds. Is there a way to detect when a client gets a timeout on server? Is there a way to detect when client disconnects from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you could not detect that the client disconnected from server without trying to perform reading or writing. To determine that the client is disconnected the server must send a packet. If the connection is closed will be thrown `IOException`.

Comment: I was afraid somebody will say something like that. :(